# C# Console.ReadLine() reading multiple lines

Tags: c#, console.readline

I'm relatively new to coding, and brand new to C#. I'm working through the Channel 9 tutorials on MSDN and I've run across something I don't understand involving Console.ReadLine().

As part of one of the tutorials, the instructor produced the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("Values.txt");
        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {
            line = myReader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        myReader.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This code works--it reads a series of numbers, each on its own line, from Values.txt and then sends them to the console window. My question is WHY it works. It's my understanding that Console.ReadLine() reads a single line from the input stream. But in this case, it's reading several lines despite not being part of the while loop. I would have expected that, as written, the console window would only display the last line of Values.txt, and that Console.ReadLine() would have to follow Console.WriteLine(line) within the if statement in order to display all lines. What am I not understanding? Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, I understand what StreamReader.ReadLine() does, and where it is. The Console.ReadLine() in question is the last line in the block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.WriteLine() is the command that outputs to the console window, and since it's part of the while loop. It prints every line from the file.

Console.ReadLine() at the end here, is only added to force the debug console window to stay open until user inputs and hits enter, usually for this case Console.ReadKey() is more appropriate.
But in the above code, Console.ReadLine() is not the code that reads numbers from the file. It's myReader.ReadLine(); in the while loop.
So the while loop, keeps reading lines from the file until it gets to the end of file.

Comment: So is it Console.WriteLine() that's actually displaying the text in the console window? So far in the tutorial, every time we've used Console.WriteLine() it's been followed by Console.ReadLine(). It always seemed counter-intuitive to me, but I chalked it up to my limited understanding. But if Console.WriteLine() is actually doing the work of displaying, and Console.ReadLine() is just in charge of the console window, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yes Console.WriteLine() display the text in the console window.

Comment: Console.ReadLine() is used to read input from user in the console window. So user can type the input, and hit enter, that's when Console.ReadLine() reads the information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish the tutorial would have mentioned how the two work in tandem.

Comment: Of course. I don't know who voted it down--I don't have voting privileges yet.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the loop executes, it reads a line.  If the line isn't null, it loops again and again until there are no more lines.  And each time it loops and the `line` isn't null, it prints the line.

This all happens before the `Console.ReadLine()` statement at the end.  All that does is pause the program so you can see the output.

Comment: Thank you! I had a fundamental misunderstanding of what the two methods were doing.